# HTML Agular Ionic reload page I route to

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, routes

When I go to a new routing page in HTML, how do I reload the new page in HTML?

```
<button ion-button routerLink="/desiredRoute" routerDirection="root">
```

edit:

I am trying to pass variables from another page.

Page1.ts: variables I want variables from

Page2.ts: variables I want to display from page1

If I load page 2, then go into page1 and change the variables, Page2 variables don't change unless I reload.

Solved:
added this to my .ts

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.route.params.subscribe(
    params => {
        /*Update Variables here*/
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: not sure what you mean. what error message are you getting?

Comment: edited to topic to reflect what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind, any variables you set in one page, are not going to be available in the second page after you route. you have 2 possible solutions:

1) Use queryParams to pass basic strings or numbers as variables through your route, which will show up on the url and can be parsed. (usually to pass an itemId or something very simple)

2) set variable values using localStorage, and then look them up after routing.